# Localization Behavior simply not working

Tags: localization, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to test the localization feature in Polymer.
I've created a new App using the new CLI.
It gives you a nice scaffolding of an app. In there I've added the code from the app-localize-behavior docs to enable it but it simply doesn't work. By doesn't work I mean that the {{localize(...)}} line doesn't show anything.

You can find my sample code in the link below:

https://gist.github.com/dallarosa/daaac2d8959026a05c1eef1d65493d6b

This is really just the scaffolding plus the entries related to app-localize-behavior, so in the gist I've only added the related code. Let me know if you actually wanna see the whole contents.

Answer (score 0):

I just very quickly looked at the issue, and it looks ok to me at first glance... except for possibly requiring to 'type' your language property:

```
language: {type: String, value: 'en'}
```